# Can we deploy Forecast Object with data?

Tags: deployment, force.com-sites, forecast

Is it possible to deploy the forecast object with all its data and related navigation over force.com site or community portal?

Answer (score 0):

well the question really is about forecast report. we have a need to share this report across community. Is there an easy way to do it?